# integrate ∫1/u du with two methods, one failing but the other succeeding?

Tags: integration

When I integrate ∫1/u du, I first change it into ∫u^-1 du, and then use the formula to get u^0/0, which is mathematically incorrect;
but if I recall the derivative of ln u is 1/u, I will get 1/u as my result of integration.

So I am wondering why the first method doesn't work out when it should give me the answer.

Comment: It's not clear why you think the first method should give you the answer. The formula $$\int x^{n}  dx = \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$$ only works for $n \ne -1$, else the RHS is undefined. You say that the derivative of $\ln u$ is $1/u$, so by the fundamental theorem of calculus it must be that $$\int \frac{1}{u} du = \ln u$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Straight application of the power formula indeed does not work because with $(x^\alpha)'=\alpha x^{\alpha-1}$, you can never get a derivative $x^{-1}$. But what if we get close to $-1$ ?

$$\int_1^x t^{\alpha-1}dt=\frac{x^{\alpha}-1}{\alpha}$$ and

$$\lim_{\alpha\to0}\frac{x^{\alpha}-1}{\alpha}=\ ?$$

> $$\log(x).$$

[image]

---

Note that this "trick" only works for a lower bound equal to $1$ (instead of $0$), which may seem artificial. But notice that $1$ works even for negative exponents.

Answer (score 1):

There are two points of view:

1. $\frac{u^0}{0}$ is not a well-defined function and studying its properties or attributes is irrelevant.
2. Based on the definition of differentiation:
   $$
   \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{(x+h)^k-x^k}{h}=\begin{cases}
   0&,\quad k=0\\
   kx^{k-1}&,\quad k\ne0
   \end{cases}.
   $$
   As observed, $\frac{1}{x}$ is not obtained anyhow from the above limit as the terms $(x+h)^k$ and $x^k$ cancel out each other for $k=0$.